# How to concatenate files which are in <!-- build:js -->?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have multiple html files in which I have usemin comment like this:


HTML 1

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor1.js -->
  <script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

HTML 2

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor2.js -->
  <script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

HTML 3

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor3.js -->
  <script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

How could I concatenate files which are between build:js via Gruntfile?
And create vendor1.js, vendor2.js and vendor3.js

Thanks in advance for your help.